# Testng terminal report

Tags: java, maven-2, terminal, testng

I run test cases from maven, that is from command line. Is there a way to see a reason why test failed in terminal output? I've tried raising verbosity in `testng.xml` to 4,hoping that it will activate `TextReporter`, which seems like class that prints, well, text reports, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mvn -Dsurefire.useFile=false ... test or [corresponding setting](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useFile) in surefire plugin configuration.